# Obtener campos de un formulario externo y completar

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema que me traiga los datos de un formulario de una página e inserte un dato ya definido en variables.

El problema es que tengo el que no sé cómo traer los datos del formulario para autocompletar.

Éste es script con los datos definidos:

```
<?php
$postData = array(
    'name' => 'Sebastian',
    'post' => 'Esto es un texto de prueba'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://scribbble.000webhostapp.com"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($data);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Actualicé los datos porque no estaban actualizados. Pero no logro que ingrese los datos al formulario.

Comment: Parece que lo que necesitas es una llamada **AJAX**. Lo que esta tecnología te permite es realizar una llamada asíncrona desde el **Javascript** a tu fichero **PHP**. De esta manera, podrías hacer que al producirse el `submit` se enviara la petición a tu fichero **PHP** y este retornara los datos a tu vista **HTML** para hacer con ellos lo pertinente.  ¡Y todo ello sin que la página se refresque! https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: Gracias phpMyGuel, la verdad estoy viendo que esto me va a llevar mas de lo esprerado, asi que voy a ir avanzando y actualizando el codigo para tener ayuda, gracias por la info.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el propósito del primer código PHP? ¿Es un intento de automatizar el envío de datos a ese formulario? ¿El PHP está en el mismo sitio que `contacto.php`?

Comment: El proposito es que recorra dos sitios de un mismo usuario, un sitio esta hecho con wordpress y el otro no. El script debe tomar esos formularios, llenarlos con los datos ya definido en variables y enviarlo. Es como un bot. El usuario solo cambia los texto. El php deberia estar en un subdominio del usuario.

Comment: Ya sabés de antemano que campos tienen los formularios? O tenés que entrar en las páginas y obtener los campos desde ahí? Por qué no envías directamente los datos al `action` de los formularios? Para qué pasar por un paso intermedio si podes enviar los datos directamente a la URL final?

Comment: Lo que quieren hacer es enviar los datos a otros formulario que estan en wordpress y otro que no es wordpress. Ahi hay otro problema. Supongamos que hay una noticia nueva, listan las tres paginas y envian la noticia a las tres, sin tener que estrar una por una. No se me ocurrio hacerlos por `GET`, tampoco se como hacerlo.

Comment: No respondiste mi pregunta, pero entonces asumo que SI saben que campos hay en esos 3 formularios. El punto es que no tienen que enviar los datos *al* formulario, sino a la página a la que apuntan los formularios. En tu ejemplo el formulario tiene un `action="envio.php"`. Con lo cual el script tiene que enviar los datos a `envio.php`, NO a `contacto.php`.

Comment: Aaaah... claro, pero no se los campos de hay en los formularios, puede sacarlos, pero no son todos iguales. Suponiendo que en wordpress haya uno que se llame: `<input name="text-name" type="text">`, no se si el otro es igual. Por ejemplo es action de uno de los wordpress es asi: `form action="/news/#wpcf7-f4751-p1964-o1` el `action="envio.php"` es un ejemplo mio

Comment: Bueno, a eso iba. Pero el punto es, pueden entrar antes a esas páginas, anotar cuales son los campos y en base a eso actualizar sus scripts? Porque eso no sería un problema. Sabés que campos te pide el "sitio 1", cuales el "sitio 2", etc. Tu script envía lo que corresponda a cada uno.

Comment: Entiendo, eso se puede guardad en una array, pero no se que hacer, la otra que me queda es tratar de traer todo con `file_get_contents` y auto completar, pero en este caso tendria que hacerlo con global o no se... ya estoy perdido

Comment: Ahi actualice el codigo para tratar de postear en un sitio. Pero como resultado me trae el sitio, aca dejo un ejemplo: [sitio de pruebas](http://metric.rf.gd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondo para que entiendas como funciona, pero vas a tener que adaptarlo para los tus casos puntuales.

Estás queriendo enviar el formulario que se encuentra en https://scribbble.000webhostapp.com. Lo primero que tenés que hacer es chequear a que URL se envía el formulario y qué parámetros se envían. Una vez que obtengas eso, tenés que simular el POST. Puede que en algunos casos con eso solo no sea suficiente, porque ellos desde el backend pueden estar chequeando alguna otra cosa.

Entré en esa URL, hice una publicación y desde la solapa "red/network" del explorador revisé los datos:

[image: Encabezados]
[image: Parámetros]
 - URL a la que se envía: https://scribbble.000webhostapp.com/ (es el `action` del formulario, en *éste* caso se envía a la misma URL donde se encuentra el formulario).
 - Parámetros:
   - name: Nombre ingresado
   - post: Texto del mensaje
   - add: *parámetro vacío*

Obtenidos los datos, los repliqué desde cURL:

```php
$postData = [
    'name' => 'Sebastian',
    'post' => 'Esto es un texto de prueba',
    'add'  => '',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://scribbble.000webhostapp.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

Si corrés ese script vas a ver que se publica el mensaje.

En este caso lo que te devuelve es el contenido del sitio con tu mensaje nuevo. Pero es poco importante lo que devuelve, lo que importa es que se publique el mensaje.

Éste proceso lo vas a tener que probar con cada uno de los sitios y tendrás que ajustar los campos según corresponda.

Comment: Gracias azeos, en `CURLOPT_URL` puedo traer un array que traiga los otros tres sitios, pero haciendo la prueba con uno, noto que me trae el sitio al localhost, como puedo evitar eso?

Comment: Probablemente estés poniendo la URL relativa del `action`, como "envio.php", tenés que poner la abosluta: "http://sitio.com/envio.php". Ahora, probablemente cada sitio tenga sus campos, así que enviar el mismo POST a todos no va a resultar. Tenés que hacer uno para cada uno. Igual insisto, olvidate de lo que trae, vos fijate si se publica la noticia.

Comment: Entiendo, en el sitio de prueba se publica bien. Si cambio a un `'submit'  => '',` no habra problema? gracias

Comment: Ningún problema, cada sitio va a tener sus campos. Modificá lo que requiera cada uno.

Comment: La pagina que estoy haciendo la prueba es: `https://mktmarketingdigital.com/contacto/` que esta hecha en wordpress, lo hago desde aca porque llegaria un mail y asi saber si funciona. Este es el array: `'your-name' => 'Sebastian',
    'your-mail' => 'sebastian@sitio.com.ar',
    'your-website' => 'sitio.com.ar',
    'your-message' => 'Esto es una prueba desde localhost',
    'submit'  => '',`

Comment: Haciendo la prueba con este sitio `https://mktmarketingdigital.com/contacto/` no funciona! No se como ver eso!

Comment: @Qodde Lo que puedo ver (no probar) es: `'_wpcf7' => '4751', '_wpcf7_version' => '5.1.3', '_wpcf7_locale' => 'en_US', '_wpcf7_unit_tag' => 'wpcf7-f4751-p1964-o1', '_wpcf7_container_post' => '1964', 'your-name' => 'Nombre', 'your-email' => 'email@example.org', 'your-website' => 'www.google.com', 'your-message' => 'El mensaje'`. Todo eso se envía a `https://mktmarketingdigital.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4751/feedback`. Pero insisto, puede haber chequeo de cookies u otras cosas.

Comment: @Qodde agregué unas imágenes para que veas de donde obtener los datos.

Comment: Gracias @azeós... voy a seguir investigando mas... muchas gracias por la info

Answer (score 0):

en la parte de arriba estas haciendo una peticion post, eso lo que hace es enviar el formulario sin validacion humana, a lo que entiendo necesitas hacer validacion humana, entonces, necesitas hacer una peticion get primero a  la primer pagina, si no tienes ninguna api puedes hacer un parseo del codigo buscando algun patron, por ejemplo clases o hasta con el mismo input name=" con la funcion preg_match_all, ahora, corrigeme si los pasos son correctos, 1. Obtener informacion de un formulario de contacto ya con datos predefinidos, 2. imprimir esos datos en otro formulario para que alguien edite y/o de click en enviar. 3. enviar el formulario.

Comment: Gracias. Claro, la idea es enviar las noticias a tres sitios distintos, 2 en wordpress y uno no. Que si el ultimo no entra, no hay problema porque seguro lo van a cambiar. Los pasos son correctos, no se si a futuro agregaran mas sitios o formularios.